# Java; New line for certain character in output with a file input

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, fileoutputstream

Basically the '{' and '}' need to be on new lines for the output. But i do not know how to read by certain characters efficiently. I have a program that reads the lines and outputs them and do not know where to start. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("textfile.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String line;        

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: The input file would be an simple java class with the { and } on the same lines as the code e.g { public static void main(String [] argv), and i would like to separate that.

Comment: If you just want to fix up the formatting of your code, use a tool like `astyle` or `indent`.

Comment: Thanks but i need to write a piece of code for it.

Comment: Then you could read in the file contents to a string with Apache Fileutils `readFileToString()`, and use a method like `String.replace()` or `String.replaceAll()`. Replace `{` with `\n{`, etc. The program would be a few lines of code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it (using org.apache.commons.io for file parsing):

## Solution

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File testFile = new File("textfile.txt");
    String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(testFile);
    fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\{", "\n{").replaceAll("}", "\n}");
    System.out.println(fileContent);
}
```

## Explanation

This will read the file to a String and replace all the occurrences of a **'{'** or **'}'** with a **'\n{'** or **'\n}'** correspondingly.

Btw. only the **'{'** character needs to be espaced via **'\\'**.

## EDIT:

### How to use the library.

Seeing that you seem to be new to Java, to use the library you have multiple options. One of them would be to use a project management tool such as "Apache Maven".

However the easiest option is to [donwload the library](https://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi)  (choose "**commons-io-2.4-bin.zip**").

Extract the file **commons-io-2.4.jar** into your project. Assuming you have a modern IDE it will know how to import the library when it is used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `String.replaceAll` method then you could add a new line and print the `{` to the new line

Here is how you could do it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("textfile.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;





        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         line=line.replaceAll("\\{", "\n{");
         line=line.replaceAll("\\}", "\n}");
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you want to read file character wise. don't read line but character

```
while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) r;
           // do your work
        }
    }
```

If you want to read line first for some reason
One you get the line

```
char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
for (Char char : chars)
{
    // check for that character and process accordingly
}
```

Comment: downvoter please help me to improve with explanation whats wrong here.